# Overhang-Attribute of Arrow not working in Annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set an overhang for the arrow style of an annotation in matplotlib. Setting the `overhang`-attribute using `Axes.arrow()` works find, setting it in the `arrowprops`-attribute of `Axes.annotate()` not.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, overhang=0.2)
ax.annotate(
    "Test",
    (0, 0.5),
    (0.5, 0),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>,head_width=1.05, head_length=1"),
)
# # Fails:
# ax.annotate(
#     "Test",
#     (0, 0.5),
#     (0.5, 0),
#     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>,head_width=1.05, head_length=1, overhang=1"),
# )
# # Fails:
# ax.annotate(
#     "Test",
#     (0, 0.5),
#     (0.5, 0),
#     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>,head_width=1.05, head_length=1", overhang=1),
#     
# )
# # Fails:
# ax.annotate(
#     "Test",
#     (0, 0.5),
#     (0.5, 0),
#     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>,head_width=1.05, head_length=1"),
#     overhang=1,
# )
plt.show()
```

Where and how can I set the `overhang`-attribute?